# cv2.imshow shows binary image

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I have a code in which the matrix hip_dir represents a RGB image. If I check its shape, python returns (1080, 1920, 3). If I write

```
cv2.imwrite('hip_dir.jpg',hip_dir)
```

I get the correct image saved in the folder. However, when I do

```
cv2.imshow('img0',hip_dir)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get the same image, in black and white (there are some blue pixels, however, making this even stranger).

How can I use imshow correctly?

Edit:

Using the command cv2.cvtColor results in the following error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.1.0) c:\projects\opencv- 
python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.simd_helpers.hpp:94: error:         
(-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::impl::`anonymous-namespace'::CvtHelper<struct cv::impl::`anonymous namespace'::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xe227985e::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xe227985e::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
Unsupported depth of input image:
 'VDepth::contains(depth)'
where
 'depth' is 6 (CV_64F)
```

Edit2: I discovered that the reason for this error to occur is simple because the matrix is in `np.float64`. Having it converted to `np.float32`, however, does not change the `imshow` result.

Comment: Adding your images (both correct and *"unhappy"* versions) to your question is always appreciated and considerably more likely to result in a useful answer when asking image processing questions...

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV expects the image to be in BGR format, try applying

```py
converted = cv2.cvtColor(hip_dir,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it raises the error (edited in the question)    .

Answer (score 1):

So guys, I discovered what was wrong: the correct way to disply the RGB colors in the imshow command is forcing the correspondent matrix of the image to be in np.uint8 format. I tested the other formats, and none of them worked properly. I don't know why, though.

Comment: The reason is that uint8 images expect values from 0..255. Images with a floating-point type expect values between 0 and 1. If you have a floating-point image with values above 1, they're all assumed to be 1. The result is a binary image with 0 = black, and 1-255 = white.